# State is contained in react redux actions vs. contained in reducers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state, react-redux

I'm learning react-redux form the todo example in the [docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html) and don't see why the id of the nextTodo is held in the `actions` rather than the `reducer`. Shouldn't this be considered state because it changes overtime as more todos are added? To me, the purpose of an action is to grab some input from the user and transform it to an action, not generate state. It is the reducer's job to create state and change it according to the actions given to it.

**Action Code**

```
let nextTodoId = 0

export const addTodo = (text) => {
  return {
    type: 'ADD_TODO',
    id: nextTodoId++,
    text
  }
}
```

**Reducer code**

```
const todo = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO':
      return {
        id: action.id,
        text: action.text,
        completed: false
      }
...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because the reducer is expected to be a pure function. That is, if you run it multiple times with the same parameters, it would return the same result, and the state of the rest of the application would not change.

For that reason, the reducer can't determine the ID, as if it did, it would cause repeated runs to have different results (i.e. different return values).

The reducer's job isn't to create state. It's job is to get the existing state and a delta (i.e. an action) and return a new state. And it should do so reliably.

Comment: so it is common practice to create state from the action? to me it seems like the component is taking care of the controller's role and then the store is the model, but not sure where the creation of state happens @madara-uchiha

Comment: how do you know not to do this logic in the container component instead? why keep it in the action

Comment: Shouldn't the `nextTodoId` be part of the state? I don't understand why it's defined as a variable outside the state if the state is supposed to contain all application state. That would also allow the reducer function to stay pure.

Comment: @lammert That's definitely another valid way of implementing it.